# Android Studio - некорректная работа каретки, не работают стандартные сочетания клавиш

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, клавиатура

Как только не пробовал - каретка возвращается обратно в это состояние:
Ноутбук, Win 10.
версии Android Studio устанавливал и последние, и предыдущие.
Insert помогает лишь на текущей вкладке проекта и при перезапуске среды всё возвращается.
Стандартные комбинации клавиш не работают, даже если менять в настройках.[insert помогает, но комбинации клавиш всё равно не работают и при нажатии комбинации каретка возвращается в исходное состояние.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В других средах разработки всё хорошо, такой проблемы нет.
При таком режиме каретки печатать тоже не получается - звучит звук, как при конфликте с другой открытой программе/окне. Как видите на скрине ниже - настройки сочетаний пытался менять, но это ничего не дало. Настройки клавиш в Android Studio и Intellij Idea одинаковые. Кэш чистил, Clean и Rebuild делал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажата ли клавиша scroll lock проверил на экранной клавиатуре - не нажата.
Прошу помощи! Так работать невозможно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема решается так:
Жмем File->Settings->Editor->General->Appearance
Смотрим активен ли чекбокс на Use block caret, если да - убираем.